# pass a parameter from view to context_processors

Tags: django, templates

I have the following structure

polls / context_processors.py:

```
def link_list(request,link):
   link = link
   data = Page.objects.filter(link=link)
   return {'link':data}
```

polls / views.py:

```
    ...
    content = {
        'content':content

    }
    link = request.POST["link"]
    template = loader.get_template('pages/pages.html')
    response = HttpResponse(template.render(content , request))
    return response
```

what I want to do is to send a parameter from views( might set for each page depending on certain scenario) and and I want to pass this parameter to context_processors as I want to use the template tag outside "pages/pages.html" template

is this possible ?

Comment: Why would you use a context processor, and not just include the `link` in the view? A `context_processor` is something that runs *each* time you render a template. This does not look like the use case for that?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  Iwant to use the template tag outside the pages/pages.html template ( header template) this is why I am using context_processor

Comment: but you do not need a context processor for that. If you render a page, and it `{% extends ... %}`, or `{% includes ... %}` then the "parent template" or "child template" has access to these variables as well. So you can still pass this to the context and use the variable in the header/footer.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem this will be my approach if I am not able to send parameters to context_processors. I thought to ask first.